# az login not listing subscriptions after `az account clear`

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I used `az account clear` while trying to solve another problem. Now `az login` no longer lists the subscriptions available for me at *portal.azure.com*. How can I fix this?

```sh
denu:~ denu$ az login
The default web browser has been opened at https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize. Please continue the login in the web browser. If no web browser is available or if the web browser fails to open, use device code flow with `az login --use-device-code`.
You have logged in. Now let us find all the subscriptions to which you have access...
denu:~ denu$ echo "No subscriptions printed :(("
No subscriptions printed :((
denu:~ denu$  az account list    --refresh    --query "[::]"    --output table
Name                    State    IsDefault    TenantId                              HomeTenantId                          CloudName
----------------------  -------  -----------  ------------------------------------  ------------------------------------  -----------
Azure subscription 1    Enabled  False        XXX                                   XXX                                   AzureCloud
Concierge Subscription  Enabled  True         XXX                                   XXX                                   AzureCloud
denu:~ denu$ echo "But I have subscriptions sooo... ???"
But I have subscriptions sooo... ???
denu:~ denu$
```

Comment: Did you login in the webpage that opened?

Comment: I do indeed. I just tried again after clearing my cookies. Still no luck; `az login` still doesn't output a list of subscriptions once logged in.

Comment: I tired clearing the account cache from local cli and then performed az login, it seems to list me the subscriptions .  may i know what version of CLI you are using ?

Comment: ```denu:azure denu$ az version
denu:azure denu$ az version --output json
{
  "azure-cli": "2.29.2",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.29.2",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.0.6",
  "extensions": {}
}
denu:azure denu$ ```

Maybe I messed up my default outputs somehow? Shouldn't `az version` just show the version?